# ClosedXML not returning correct cell value

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am trying to get the value of a cell. In Excel it is displayed as `0.22` (formatted as number, `0.00`). In the underlying Excel sheetXX.xml file the value is

```
<v>0.21970469798657719</v>
```

The value is the result of a formula.

When I try to access that cell from ClosedXML in C# I get `0`.

```
sheet.Cell(22, 5).GetValue<double>(); // = 0
```

Same for

```
sheet.Cell(22, 5).CachedValue
sheet.Cell(22, 5).Value
sheet.Cell(22, 5).GetString()
```

etc...

I can see while debugging that the `sheet.Cell(22, 5).InnerText` property is correct though I don't know how to access that while not debugging.

No Exception is thrown at any point.

Why is ClosedXML not returning the correct value?

Comment: What about `var testVal = sheet.Cell(22, 5).RichText.ToString();` does the value return or how about `var forStr = sheet.Cell(22, 5).GetFormattedString();`

Comment: `sheet.Cell(22 5).HasRichText` is true and `sheet.Cell(row, 5).RichText.ToString()` is "0"

Comment: Though it looks like after I try to access the RichText property the InnerText value changes to "0"

Comment: Interesting, Ill see if I can replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that trying to access a cell with some `.GetValue<T>()` method will either work or zero out the value so that subsequent attempts to access it by another means are unsuccessful. If, instead of ever using `.GetValue<T>()`, you only use

```
 double.TryParse(sheet.Cell(row, col).CachedValue.ToString(), out var valueOfInterst);
```

it is much more reliable.